# Getting module Injection error with Angularjs ui-bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to use [Angularjs Bootstrap UI](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) in my application.after angular.js reference i include these files in my index pages :

and in my application `app.js` include this line :

```
var ap = angular.module('ap', ['ngRoute','ui.bootstrap']).config(negsotimeRouter);
```

but i get this error when try to see the page :

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$injector/modulerr?p0=negsotime&p1=Error…arjs.org%2F1.2.16%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3Dui.bootstrap%26p1%3DErro...<omitted>...5) angular.js:36
```

with the following link 
[Error Link](http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/%24injector/modulerr?p0=negsotime&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.16%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3Dui.bootstrap%26p1%3DErro)

Comment: do you need that config? try removeing it ? `var ap = angular.module('ap', ['ngRoute','ui.bootstrap']);`

Comment: Yes. `negsotimeRouter` is my router function

Comment: And you have misspelled `<scripttype`

Comment: if fix it . the error style happen

Comment: check if all included files are loaded, by CTRL+ U and search for file names. Another misspelled is that you haven`t closed boostrap script tag...

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26615918/error-injectornomod-module-ui-bootstrap-is-not-available-you-either-miss

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the script reference to the Angular UI Bootstrap script itself. You need to download it and make a reference to it.

For instance the latest version: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/gh-pages/ui-bootstrap-0.6.0.min.js

All versions here: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/gh-pages

As you can see, the angular ui.bootstrap module is defined in that script.

Comment: And how should he make the reference? And it should be afer the main AngularJs ?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but I will post what worked for me.

I downloaded the js file from https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/gh-pages/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.3.0.min.js

Placed it in a directory with my other angular scripts

Made a reference to it in the Index.html file using a `<Script>` tag.