# Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ui.bootstrap' is not available! You either misspelled [...]

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bower

I am having this problem here and I haven't gotten any consistent solution so far looking out there. I am running a Java project with Angular on the front-end, and trying to implement an autocomplete feature using ui-bootstrap, but I always get this error.

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module textChangrApp due to: Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ui.bootstrap due to: Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ui.bootstrap' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument. http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.4/$injector/nomod?p0=ui.bootstrap
    at http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:80:12
    at http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1787:17
    at ensure (http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1711:38)
    at module (http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1785:14)
    at http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4024:22
    at forEach (http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:330:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4008:5)
    at http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4025:40
    at forEach (http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:330:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4008:5) http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.4/$injector/modulerr?p0=ui.bootstrap&p…2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A4008%3A5)
    at http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:80:12
    at http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4047:15
    at forEach (http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:330:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4008:5)
    at http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4025:40
    at forEach (http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:330:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4008:5)
    at createInjector (http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3948:11)
    at doBootstrap (http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1480:20)
    at bootstrap (http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1501:12) http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.4/$injector/modulerr?p0=textChangrApp&…F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A1501%3A12) angular.js:80(anonymous function) angular.js:80(anonymous function) angular.js:4047forEach angular.js:330loadModules angular.js:4008createInjector angular.js:3948doBootstrap angular.js:1480bootstrap angular.js:1501angularInit angular.js:1395(anonymous function) angular.js:24904trigger angular.js:2715eventHandler angular.js:2986



//index.html
    <head>
        <!-- ... -->
        <script src="../bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
        <script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="../bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script>
        <script src="../bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
        <script src="../bower_components/hammerjs/hammer.js"></script>
        <script src="../bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.js"></script>
    </head>
//app.js
    angular
      .module( 'textChangrApp', [ 'ngAnimate', 'ngMaterial','directive.g+signin', 'ui.bootstrap'])
```

I feel like there must be something wrong in my `<head>` when importing, since it was working fine so far, and now it crashed. Hope you can give me a little help on this.

Thank you.

Comment: You need to include bootstrap after angularjs. `<script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script><script src="../bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>`

Comment: that's right. simple like this. It took me longer to write it then to wait for the answer! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You must load the ui.boostrap module **after** the angularjs file.

Answer (score 5):

Another way to install this via bower and here are the instructions.

Add the following 2 packages to bower.json in your directory.

```
"bootstrap": "*",
"angular-bootstrap": "*",
```

[image]

Run `bower update` from your directory

Add the `ui.bootstrap` to angular module like below.

[image]

Wire it in the view for the bootsrap to work

CSS

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

JS

```
<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to include following after angular.min....

```
<script src="..//ui-bootstrap-custom-tpls-0.12.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```